# PhpStorm - Symfony Duplicate Entity Suggestions

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I have been using PhpStorm 2017.3.4 with the Symfony plugin for a while. And for a long time, I'm annoyed with the following bug.

When I try to use autocompletion on PhpStorm every "entity" is listed twice, as follows:

[image]

Although I [reported this issue](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1068) to the official repository I couldn't get any response in three months.

So I would like to ask for your suggestions.

Comment: Considering that this particular list of completion items is provided by the Symfony plugin ... I doubt that the issue is on IDE side.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from us?

Comment: try to clear phostorm cache. Navigate =  File -> Invalidate Caches /Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: @LazyOne If I can verify, I'll try to go with the Jetbrains support; however they tend to blame the plugin side.

Comment: @goto As I concluded my original post, "I ask for your suggestions." to resolve the issue.

Comment: @habibun I did it lots of times however it didn't make any sense.

Comment: Try clearing the caches as suggested above -- that's the best that I can suggest from IDE side. The rest depends on plugin (why it lists it twice)... PhpStorm/IDE devs will be correct here. In those rare cases where I saw tickets for duplicate entries provided by some bundled plugin (e.g. Spelling etc) .. it was fixed in that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem and decided to post the details here for future reference.

First of all I don't know the exact root cause of the issue however it is somehow related with the **deployment** configuration. In my project, I have a deployment configuration and every change I made on my local machine is uploaded to the remote server on the background automatically.

While digging the issue, I tried to remove configuration files under `.idea` folder of my project one by one and removing the `deployment.xml` resolved the issue. Then, I reverted the deletion of the deployment.xml.

Tried find some integration of deployment on the plugin side and on the Symfony plugin configuration dialog found the following misterious, mighty checkbox:

[image: Download remote files (exp.)]

Enabling it and restarting the IDE made the issue gone. I suppose, this checkbox needs further clarification and documentation so I'll create an issue on the plugin's repo.

Let met use the chance to thank @LazyOne and @habibun for their kind assistance.